# What is the difference between versions like 20H or 20A for LG G3?

Tags: custom-roms, stock-android, lg-g3

LG G3 phones are named differently like: `F400` is Korean, `D855` is international, `D850` is for USA AT&T, `D851` is for USA T-Mobile etc.

However, ROMs for G3 are named like this: `[LG][G3][D855][20V]`

What does the [20x] part stand for?